# Ни одним способом не работает медиа-запрос

Tags: css3, html5, media-queries

В коде есть блок с классом `.menu`:

Весь блок нужно скрыть в мобильной версии, я пишу запрос такого вида:

```css
.menu {
  background-color: #000;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <span class="logo" id="logo-color">AK</span>
  <nav>
    <a href="#home" class="menu__button"><img src="img/home.png" alt="home" class="menu__icon" title="Home Screen"></a>
    <a href="#work" class="menu__button"><img src="img/works.png" alt="works" class="menu__icon" title="Works"></a>
    <a href="#contacts" class="menu__button"><img src="img/contacts.png" alt="Contacts" class="menu__icon" title="Contacts"></a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Этот запрос не срабатывает, я пробовал изменить порядок основного стиля и медиа запроса, пробовал прописывать правила screen и no screen. Что я делаю не так и какие есть способы решения данной сложности?

Comment: Все работает.
P.S. `float` и `position:fixed` не работают вместе.

Comment: Я запустил этот код на мобильном телефоне, и меню не отобразилось. Всё отлично работает

Comment: Возможно, на настоящей странице вы забыли тег meta viewport

Comment: Да, не было meta viewport, после его добавления все заработало. Спасибо